# Can I use a condition to define a type in an interface?

Tags: typescript, types, interface

I have this interface for an item:

```
interface IItem {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  description: string;
  note: string | undefined;
  type: string;
  sellable: boolean;
  buyable: boolean;
  usable: boolean;
  price: number | undefined; // <--- only undefined when both buyable and sellable are false
  usage: string;
}
```

Because I define the items, I know that price will always be a number unless sellable and buyable is false. But as of right now, TypeScript doesn't know that. Which causes me to have to add tautologic typeguards: `if (buyable)` will still require another if statement: `if (price)`, even though I know that will always be a number because of the previous if statement.

Pseudo example:

```
  sellable: bool
  buyable: bool
  price: if !sellable & !buyable: undefined else number
```

Comment: You are conflating (at least) two things: an Item and a PurchaseItem.

Comment: Not in a specific interface, no.  Could you use a union type instead as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/NaEjoN)?  If so I'll write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: I don’t think it does require that, as you can see from the playground link

Comment: Sorry my bad, you were right! Thank you and phil-gl for the help. Also accidentally deleted the comment instead of editing it mb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this using some additional types and [type union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types).

Start defining your types

```js
type A1 = {
  sellable: false;
  buyable: false;
  price: undefined;
};

type A2 = {
  sellable: boolean;
  buyable: true;
  price: number;
};

type A3 = {
  sellable: true;
  buyable: boolean;
  price: number;
};
```

Then, create a union type using all types defined above:

```js
type A = A1 | A2 | A3;
```

Finally, you can define your type `IItem` as

```js
type IItem = A & {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  description: string;
  note: string | undefined;
  type: string;
  usable: boolean;
  usage: string;
}
```